# Is it possible to check if another app has been granted a permission on Android 6.0+?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I want to check if another app has been granted a "dangerous" or "system" level permission.

I have tried loading another app's context and calling [`packageContext.checkCallingPermission(permission)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission(java.lang.String)). However, the documentation says it returns

> PERMISSION_GRANTED if the calling pid/uid is allowed that permission, or PERMISSION_DENIED if it is not.

Is it possible to check if another app has been granted a permission?

Here is my attempt (I wrote it before realizing it checks the calling pid/uid and doesn't seem to consider the context):

```
void checkAllGrantedPermissions(Context context) {
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

  // get all installed apps with info about what permissions they requested.
  List<PackageInfo> packageInfos = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

  // Get the hidden method PermissionInfo#protectionToString(int) so we can log info about the requested permission
  Method protectionToString;
  try {
    protectionToString = PermissionInfo.class.getDeclaredMethod("protectionToString", int.class);
    if (!protectionToString.isAccessible()) protectionToString.setAccessible(true);
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }

  // loop through all installed apps
  for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packageInfos) {

    if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions == null) {
      // No permissions are requested in the AndroidManifest
      continue;
    }

    String appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;

    // loop through all requested permissions in the AndroidManifest
    for (String permission : packageInfo.requestedPermissions) {

      PermissionInfo permissionInfo;
      try {
        permissionInfo = pm.getPermissionInfo(permission, 0);
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("unknown permission '%s' found in '%s'", permission, packageName));
        continue;
      }

      // convert the protectionLevel to a string (not necessary, but useful info)
      String protLevel;
      try {
        protLevel = (String) protectionToString.invoke(null, permissionInfo.protectionLevel);
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
        protLevel = "????";
      }

      // Create the package's context to check if the package has the requested permission
      Context packageContext;
      try {
        packageContext = context.createPackageContext(packageName, 0);
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException wtf) {
        continue;
      }

      int ret = packageContext.checkCallingPermission(permission);
      if (ret == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s [%s] is denied permission %s (%s)",
            appName, packageName, permission, protLevel));
      } else {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s [%s] has granted permission %s (%s)",
            appName, packageName, permission, protLevel));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Take a look at the Settings app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/AppPermissions.java#L108)

Comment: @adneal Thank you! I also needed to check for the `REQUESTED_PERMISSION_REQUIRED` flag. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: this question should not be closed. the answer below is in fact the right answer. the referenced question is closed itself for being too vague and does not answer the question appropriately. someone on SO has diligently closed all questions relating to this topic and it is currently not possible to add new approaches without creating a new redundant question on it. SAD

Comment: @rds please reopen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is it possible to check if another app has been granted a permission?

Yep. You can retrieve the flags for each [`<uses-permission>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestUsesPermission) tag in the Manifest for a given package using [`PackageInfo.requestedPermissionsFlags`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissionsFlags) then compare those flags using a bitwise operation with [`PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED).

> I want to check if another app has been granted a "dangerous" or
>   "system" level permission.

You can perform this check using [`PackageManager.getPermissionInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPermissionInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) then compare [`PermissionInfo.protectionLevel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#protectionLevel) to one of [`PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#PROTECTION_DANGEROUS) or [`PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_SIGNATURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#PROTECTION_SIGNATURE).

**For example**:

```
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    // Loop each package requesting <manifest> permissions
    for (final PackageInfo pi : pm.getInstalledPackages(GET_PERMISSIONS)) {
        final String[] requestedPermissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
        if (requestedPermissions == null) {
            // No permissions defined in <manifest>
            continue;
        }
        // Loop each <uses-permission> tag to retrieve the permission flag
        for (int i = 0, len = requestedPermissions.length; i < len; i++) {
            final String requestedPerm = requestedPermissions[i];
            // Retrieve the protection level for each requested permission
            int protLevel;
            try {
                protLevel = pm.getPermissionInfo(requestedPerm, 0).protectionLevel;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown permission: " + requestedPerm, e);
                continue;
            }
            final boolean system = protLevel == PROTECTION_SIGNATURE;
            final boolean dangerous = protLevel == PROTECTION_DANGEROUS;
            final boolean granted = (pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i]
                    & REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0;
        }
    }
```

**For more information check out:**

- [The Settings application](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/AppPermissions.java)
- [R.attr.protectionLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#protectionLevel)
- [PermissionInfo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.java#L182)

Comment: Hey bro it is not working on all the application please try viber application

Comment: In viber it is showing all app permission to be true even i have disable all the permissions

Comment: Granted permission != requested permission.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman `final boolean granted = (pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i]
                    & REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0;`?

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. After `final boolean granted = (pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0;` I have `granted == true`, but I disabled SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission for all applicaions on my device manually.

Comment: these flags are bitwise ints that get compounded but never flip another flags unique bit hence we use bitwise `and` to check if the flag is raised. Be mindfull to use `PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED` which corresponds  to 0000 0010 or 2 but if you get 3 or 6 it would also mean the permission is granted (it would only mean that another flag appart from permission-granted is also raised). hope this helps someone as clueless as I was