# Change permission of another app from our app in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to implement a feature in which I can change permission of other app through my app like  permission manager application.

Comment: This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices or *maybe* from a device owner app.

Comment: that doesn't sound very safe, so it probably isn't possible and for a good reason

Answer (score 1):

It's true you cannot directly control other apps' permissions.
But, there are some things you can do.

You can refer the user for specific application info screen (one click away from permissions screen):

```
String package = "some.app.package";
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
Uri.fromParts("package", package, null)));
```

Also you can know all of the permissions of another app (along with which of those are granted and which are automatically granted) - see the accepted answer for the following answer:
[Is it possible to check if another app has been granted a permission on Android 6.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164716/is-it-possible-to-check-if-another-app-has-been-granted-a-permission-on-android)

Now you can create permission manager app :)

Comment: That app uses accessibility permission and not for accessibility purposes. The moral solution is to refer users to permissions screen and not taking control over their device (in my opinion at least)

Comment: [link check here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shexa.permissionmanager)

Comment: how we can do it with accessibility?

Comment: I have no experience with accessibility, but I know it's a power no one should have, except accessibility apps.